# Finding controls in item template on infragistics webdropdown in code behind

Tags: c#, infragistics

I have created an Infragistics WebDropDown with a WebDataGrid in the ItemTemplate.  The problem is that in the code behind, it says that wddAddresses has no controls nor any templates and the ItemTemplate is null.  How do I "find" the WebDataGrid in the code behind?  The markup for the controls is below.

Thanks,
Dan

```
<ig:WebDropDown 
  ID="wddAddresses" 
  runat="server" 
  Width="200px" 
  DropDownContainerWidth="500px" 
  ClientEvents-ValueChanging="wddAddresses_ValueChanging">
  <DropDownItemBinding TextField="city" ValueField="addressID" />
  <ItemTemplate>
    <ig:WebDataGrid ID="gridAddresses" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      Height="350px" Width="400px" >
      <Columns>
        <ig:BoundDataField 
          DataFieldName="street1" 
          Key="street1">
          <Header Text="Street" />
        </ig:BoundDataField>
      </Columns>
      <Behaviors>
        <ig:Selection 
          CellClickAction="Row" 
          RowSelectType="Single" 
          SelectionClientEvents-RowSelectionChanged="gridAddresses_RowSelectionChanged">
        </ig:Selection>
      </Behaviors>
    </ig:WebDataGrid>
  </ItemTemplate>
</ig:WebDropDown>
```

Comment: Could you show the code behind that fails?

Comment: @Dan What is it that you are looking to accomplish?  I am asking because the code provided would use a different WebDataGrid for every item in the drop down and to me it would feel unusual to select a grid of items in the drop down.  If you are looking for a multi-column drop down then you would be better off following the either the sample with a Table or using the WebDataGrid: http://www.infragistics.com/products/aspnet/sample/drop-down/templates Note that the example showing the WebDataGrid only has a single item in the drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: from Petar at Infragistics support.

Templated controls may be accessed throught WebDropDown's items. Example below;

```
(WebDropDown1.Items[0].FindControl("Button1") as Button).Text = "new text";
```